# can we get the latest available avg quarterly income of each user with nested group by ? sqlite

Tags: sqlite, nested, nested-loops

Can we find the average of latest available quarterly income of each user with nested  group by ? sqlite ( been thinking about it for a while please comment  if something is not clear)
**updated** with one restriction: do without case since it requires us to know 3 ahead of time(seem to me not vary practical)

Let's say we have the income table as:

```
income: uid (string), jobid (string), month (string), quarter(string), year (integer), earned (integer)
          A01                uber      jan             w               2021                     2500         
          A01                uber      dec             f               2020                     1500                  
          A01                uber      nov             f               2020                     2000                  
          A01                uber      oct             f               2020                     1500                  
          A01                uber      sep             f               2020                     2000                  
          A01                uber      aug             f               2020                     1500                  


          A03                  dj      aug             f               2020                     1500                  
          A03                  dj      jul             f               2020                     2000                  
          A03                  dj      jun             f               2020                     1500                  
          A03                  dj      may             s               2020                     2000                  

          A02                chef      nov             f               2020                     2000                  
          A02                chef      oct             f               2020                     1500                  
          A02                chef      sep             f               2020                     2000
```

would like use one query to return (order by uid if possible):

```
 A01                w                     2021                     2500    
 A02                f                     2020                     1833.33 
 A03                f                     2020                     1666.66
```

What I have so far:

```
select uid, quarter,year, avg(earned) 
from income 
group by year, quarter;
```

Which returns:

```
     A01                w                     2021                     2500    
     A01                f                     2020                     1700    
     A03                f                     2020                     1666.66    
     A03                s                     2020                     2000    

     A02                f                     2020                     1833.33
```

notice how

```
 A01                f                     2020                     1700             
 A03                s                     2020                     2000
```

is extra here, I know we can run another query to eliminate, but can someone think of getting the desired result with one query?

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: let's say we are in banking bus. then we would like to know how each user doing financially?  Getting the latest available avg quarterly income?

Comment: To be more specific: Why do you only expect fall quarter for `A01` and spring quarter for `A03`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you are right,  chronological order is w, s, then f,  we would like to get the latest available average quarterly income.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a `CASE` expression to identify the latest year and quarter.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT uid, year, quarter, AVG(earned) AS avg_earned,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid
                              ORDER BY year DESC, CASE quarter WHEN 'f' THEN 3
                                                               WHEN 's' THEN 2
                                                               WHEN 'w' THEN 1 END DESC) rn
    FROM income
    GROUP BY uid, year, quarter
)

SELECT uid, year, quarter, avg_earned
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: Can we do without row_number and case ? seem like we know there are 3 ahead of time which not vary practical? ( Or it is common practice)   ? if you can add a bit explanation that is more appreciated .

Comment: This is the only way I know how to easily write your query.  You want, for each user, the latest year, and then also the latest quarter, with `f` being more recent than `s`, being more recent than `w`.

Comment: yes, can we do something using < to compare  or  group by quarter desc; ?