# SQLlite getting min and max and average using nested queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these tables

```
record: sid (string), cid (string), quarter (string), year (integer), grade(integer)
student: sid (string)
```

For every student who has taken at least one class, meaning a student is entered in the record table at least once, i need to get their GPA in the most recent quarter they were enrolled in. I need to display sid, quarter, year, and grade (gpa).

There are 3 quarters in a given calendar year, and it may be helpful to observe the order of the occurrence of quarters is in reverse alphabetical order ('W' > 'S' > 'F'). These stands for winter, spring, fall respectively. Fall being the latest quarter of the year.

this is what i came up with:

```
select sid, quarter, year, avg(grade) as gpa
from (select sid, min(quarter) as quarter, year, avg(grade) as grade
    from (select *, max(year) as maxy
        from record
        group by sid)
    group by sid)
group by sid;
```

this gives me the average grade for all quarters/years enrolled, and doesn't give me the latest quarter either.

I can only use functions such as NOT EXIST / EXIST, NOT IN/IN , group by, order by. I cannot use rank().

I was told that I should use NOT EXIST to get the latest quarter since the most recent quarter means for a specific quarter, there is no succeeding quarter.

any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: This looks very similar to [another recent SQLite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894918/can-we-get-the-latest-available-avg-quarterly-income-of-each-user-with-nested-gr/65895194?noredirect=1#comment116507958_65895194) which was asked recently.  Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

You want solution using `not exists`? Here you go.

```
Select t.*
  From record t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from record tt
         Where tt.year > t.year
           And tt.quarter < t.quarter
           And tt.sid = t.sid)
```

Above query will give you all the data of student for latest quarter, then you can use the aggregate function according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sid
                                order by case quarter when 'W' then 1 when 'S' then 2 when 'F' then 3 else 4 end desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from records r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Although this can be simplified a little bit by relying on the "alphabetical" ordering of `quarter`, I don't recommend that approach.  Relying on alphabetic ordering for time periods is counterintuitive and will make the code harder to understand.

If the `quarter` were stored as a *number* then it would be appropriate for use in `order by`.